# Dynamic Programmatic variable initialization

Tags: swift, dynamic

I have a large number of variables that are loaded via a file into a dictionary.  There is a UI for the user to edit these values, which can then be saved back to a file.  So there are several good reasons for also keeping the names and values in a dictionary.  For brevity here, I will use an example of 3 instead of the hundreds that exist in my app.  In the app, these variables are used very frequently, so I was hoping to get around repeatedly referencing the dictionary.

If I want to set actual variables, currently I have to do this:

```
//definitions
var size: double
var width: double
var height: double

let varDict = ["size":5.0, "width":100.0, "height":50.0]

//setting values
size = varDict["size"]
width = varDict["width"]
height = varDict["height"]
```

In order for the compiler to function, I understand each variable will still need to be defined (as per the //definitions section)

Is there any way in Swift (version 4+) to do this (the //setting values section) in a loop, without having to specify each one as a separate explicit command?  I know some languages such a Lisp can do this.

Or are my only choices to update a routine by hand, or write a program to generate Swift source whenever my list of variables gets updated, and paste that into my source code?

Comment: Have you considered using a `Codable` type, such as a struct, to handle this? It can be written to and read from disk with minimal effort, and if you like, serialized as JSON. Using such a type, you'd simply read your dictionary into an instance of it and not need all these variables.

Comment: That's a great idea, and I will try to make that work.  But it then begs the question in regards to how they make that work.  Since the struct defines all the fields, the compiler will know about them, but how does the Codable protocol do reflection (which Swift doesn't currently have) on the contents to know how to set a value?  And aside from knowing about a given variable, how does it actually set the value of a variable if it didn't know the name of the variable at compile time?

Comment: First, it is not correct to say that Swift lacks reflection. The API for it undeveloped and a bit awkward, but you may use `Mirror` to perform reflection. They plan on improving the API in future releases. As for `Decodable`, the compiler generates two components for you at build time. One is a property to key map called `CodingKeys` and other is an initializer called `init(decoder:)`. You may also implement these yourself for more custom decoding needs. If you also adopt `Encodable`, an addition encoding method is generated.

Comment: woodcutting - I stand corrected regarding reflection, and I am aware of Mirror.  Unfortunately, Mirror provides the label and value only, and not an equivalent keyPath.  Consequently, I can use it to read properties, but not to modify them.  Also unfortunately, CodingKeys has a Private protection level, so is inaccessible.  I have been able to write a piece of code that allows me to access and modify each of the properties using a loop with non-hard-coded lines, but in order to make it work, it still requires a single hard-coded line for each property during initialization.

Comment: Have you had a chance to review https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types? If all properties share a name with the corresponding key, the compiler does all the work. This is also true if the names are identical but cased differently. For both decoding and encoding to work, all you need to declare is the protocol adoption. If you wish to have custom key property mapping, you must define that map. Finally, if you wish to do custom transformations during decoding, you will need to write them yourself, as you suggest.

Comment: woodcutting - I am trying to do something similar to Codable, but only similar.  I am not trying to encode/decode between a JSON string and a struct.  I am in effect trying to encode/decode between a struct and a dictionary (or something similar), such that I can work with and edit the values as a list, before I return them to the struct.  I am trying to get access to the variables in a way similar to what Codable does, and even after having gone through the Foundation code, can't seem to determine how Codable does it.

Answer (score 0):

Such "dynamic" variables don't exist in Swift.

In swift the compiler has to know exactly, which variables exist, which types they have etc., because it is a statically typed language, which is one of the most important features of it, because it is very safe to use.

But the compiler can't know which variables your loop would create, because you could change your variable source file without recompiling your app.

Comment: Josef - Understood, and thanks for the answer.  As stated above, I know I have to create the variables.  I am just asking about setting them. (the //setting values section)

Comment: This also doesn't work because the compiler wants to know also, which variables it sets when. I'm sorry but what you want is against every rule of statically typed languages.

Comment: Joseph, not true.  Swift allows for an Any type.  You simply have to guard against a failure before setting it.  What I am looking for is a derivative of what the Swift Codable protocol already does.  So I think we are just going to have to disagree on this one.